# RadEditor requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, telerik, httphandler, radeditor

When I add this code to my `aspx` ,

```
   <telerik:RadEditor ID="REWelcome" runat="server" 
    AutoResizeHeight="True" Width="500px" ToolbarMode="Floating">
   <Content>
   </Content>
   <TrackChangesSettings CanAcceptTrackChanges="False"></TrackChangesSettings>
   </telerik:RadEditor>
```

And I got this error message ,

```
'~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config.  
 RadScriptManager requires a   
 HttpHandler registration in web.config.
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your web.config - add the following to the system.web (omit the system.web, just used to show you level:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false" />
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"></add>
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"></add>
    </httpHandlers>
```

The bottom two are not needed gnerally but I am assuming you want the extended features of the editor, like dialogs and spellchecking.

I also add location at the same level as system.web

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This got me close - but I also had to add it to the <system.webServer> section after upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2013.  Thanks!!
<system.webServer> <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> <handlers> <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />

Comment: AH Why don't they tell us things are going to break everywhere when upgrading! Dang VS 2013.....I added your code to my system.webServer section and it worked like a charm. Thanks for including your extra note. :)

Comment: There is a help article about that, by the way: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/web-config-settings-overview.html

Comment: @hardba11 you should consider adding that as an answer. It just saved me from a lot of googling.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to add the Telerik.Web.UI.dll file in the bin folder of your application.
That worked for me.

Comment: It should be a comment

Answer (score 2):

These are the handlers needed for RadEditor and RadScriptManager:

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

source: http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-web-ui-webresource-axd-is-missing-in-web-config-f25e27e5a5ac

Answer (score 1):

if the error message is like this::

~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config. RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config. Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager

Then you add the following into your web.config file:::

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the ASP Application pool from "Integrated" to "Classic" mode. All my configurations were correct, as described in other posts here. This is probably specific to my configuration, but may be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while deploying to IIS 7.

You could set the Managed pipeline mode from Integrated to Classic. This indeed solves the problem with behaving IIS 7.5 as old 6.0 (with handler registered in old web.config node), but I wasn’t convinced that to use Telerik’s controls, I should use old type of pipeline.

Our old web.config file registered Telerik’s handler only in old  section for IIS 6 (and that sufficed for cassini and IIS 6.0) and not in new  section.

So I had to add this piece of xml to web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"  path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed KB article on this matter including all possible reasons for the error and how to fix it. Please check it out at [Error: Web.config registration missing! The Telerik dialogs require a HttpHandler registration in the web.config file](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/details/error-web-config-registration-missing!-the-telerik-dialogs-require-a-httphandler-registration-in-the-web-config-file-).

One of the best solutions is to open the web.config file and replace Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx with Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_axd"/>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and after that to set the RadEditor's DialogHandlerUrl property to "~/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd", i.e.

Comment: Note the remove, for me, that is added before the add.  But somehow the order got swapped, and add then remove just doesn't work....

Answer (score -1):

I got this error today when copying a published copy of a site from one server to another.

I figured that I shouldn't have to modify any scripts or code to get it to work again, after all, the site still worked just fine on its old server it is still being hosted on.

This is what I believe happened:

1. I copied the site files over, hooked up a site and bindings to it in IIS, and then tried to run it.
2. I got errors, and was forced to modify file handler bindings, the .net framework version of the app pool, and install new server roles/features to get it to at least produce this error.
3. I then deleted everything in the folder and re-copied the site files and it started working again.

IIS must have modified my site files in some way that prevented the site from working, and restoring the original code fixed it.

I know this is a very specific set of circumstances, but hopefully if someone else has the same situation some day they can solve it in the same simple way that I did.