# Telerik SpellChecker: RadEditor requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config

Tags: asp.net, telerik, web-config, httphandler, radeditor

I am creating a web app in asp.net, I have a Radeditor, when I clicked on Ajax spellcheck, I am getting the error of

> Web.Config Registration Missing!
>
> The SpellChecking Functionality Requires a HttpHandler registration in
>   web.config, please use the control smart tag to add the handler
>   automatically, or see the help for more information.
>
> Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd

My web.config look like the below

HttpHandler

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="true" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Handler

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
  <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Location

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Error on page

[image]

What else should I add in web.config, as I try to work with [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230694/radeditor-requires-a-httphandler-registration-in-web-config) solution but still facing the same problem

After Implementing Rumen Jekov Solution, I am still getting the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the Spell Check Handler Server Error, AjaxUrl property is used to set the path to the handler and is used in scenarios where you may have a UrlRewriter module which overwrites the handlers url even if they are set in the web.config. A correct value of this property is like follows: RadEditor1.SpellCheckSettings.AjaxUrl = "Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.aspx";

Once you set the new AjaxUrl value, go to the web.config file and update the Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd instances to Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.aspx

Check this article for more information about problems with handlers: https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/details/error-web-config-registration-missing!-the-telerik-dialogs-require-a-httphandler-registration-in-the-web-config-file-

Comment: Still I am getting the error, checkout my question, edited it

Comment: yes answer actually solved my issue in my case I need to add `RadEditor1.SpellCheckSettings.AjaxUrl = "~/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.aspx";`